# vscode Find and replace across files, backreference is repeated the if more than one match is on the same line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am searching across files in `vscode` using the following regex expression

`(?<=[a-zA-Z])_([a-zA-Z])` with `$1`

to replace `Some_Random_Text` with `SomeRandomText`

but vs code repeats the backreference value if they are on the same line as shown below `S` is repeated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sure looks like a bug to me.  It does not happen in the Find in the current file widget.  You should file an issue on this - probably due to the Search across files handling the lookbehind (which should be no problem since it is fixed-width).

In the meantime, you can easily remove the lookbehind part and use:

find: `([a-zA-Z])_([a-zA-Z])`
replace: `$1$2`

which works as it should.

Comment: Maybe this is not going to be a problem here, but please note that this will make it impossible to replace consequent occurrences.